# Why am I losing precision when reading in IEEE-754 floating point from a file encoded in 32-bit binary big endian?

Tags: c, matlab, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I am re-writing some Matlab file processing code in pure C, and I've implemented the following function that will read 4 bytes from a binary big endian encoded file that should be representing an ieee-754 single precision floating point value. I verified that I'm able to pull the relevent 32-bit data out of the file as an unsigned integer with the following code.

```
int fread_uint32_be(uint32_t *result, FILE ** fp)
{
    uint8_t data[sizeof(uint32_t)];
    if (!result || !*fp || sizeof(uint32_t) != fread((void *) data, 1, sizeof(uint32_t), *fp))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    *result = ((uint32_t)(data[0]) << 24 | (uint32_t)(data[1]) << 16 |
               (uint32_t)(data[2]) << 8  | (uint32_t)(data[3]));
    return 0;
}
```

The data I'm expecting has a hex value of `0x1acba506` as returned from this function, and was verified by a hex dump of the data file in big endian format. Now here comes my problem...

When I cast this value from `uint32_t` to `float`, I get a single precision floating point value of `449553664.000000` which is close but not exactly what the Matlab code had, which was `449553670.000000`.  I've verified that when Matlab reads the binary file, it also gets the same hex value `0x1acba506` that my C code has.

When I cast back from `float` to `uint32_t` and print the hex value, I end up with `0x1acba500`, which shows that I'm losing precision in the simple cast i.e. `float ans = (float)result;` but I don't really understand why? I'm using gcc 7.4 on an x86 machine, and I've verified that `sizeof float == sizeof uint32`. Am I making a poor assumption that the compiler is using IEEE-754 single precision floating point?

In debugging, I found an [online calculator for floating point](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that makes it seem like the precision is hopelessly lost, but then the question becomes how is Matlab retaining it?

[image: Here is the number I'm getting by casting to float in my C code]

[image: Here is the number that I see in the Matlab code]

Comment: I would suggest posting a minimal complete example code that demonstrates the issue. Note that `449553670` is not representable as a `float`, and that `449553664.0f` is the closest `float` representation. `449553670` is however representable as a `double`, and this is presumably the data type used by Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mantissa of IEEE 754 *single-precision* float is 24 bits, where the first bit is implied 1.

Let's see your two integers - Python is a good tool for debugging these. Their bit representations are

```
>>> format(449553664, '032b')
'00011010110010111010010100000000'
```

and

```
>>> format(449553670, '032b')
'00011010110010111010010100000110'
```

Now, if we look into the latter number and see how it would fit into a single-precision mantissa, the first 1 bit is the 4th bit from left, and including that we count 24 bits, and we get

```
>>> format(449553670, '032b').lstrip('0')[:24]
'110101100101110100101000'
```

Clearly the last `110` did not fit into the mantissa and the value was rounded down. Therefore the value of `(float)449553670` is presented as

```
1.10101100101110100101000b * 10b ^ 11100b
```

i.e. in decimal

```
1.67471790313720703125 * 2 ^ 28
```

which equals 449553664.0.

---

Matlab most likely retains the precision by not using floats but doubles, just like JavaScript does. All integers with width less than 53 bits can be represented in IEEE 754 *double-precision floats*.

Answer (score 2):

A single-precision floating point number fits in a 32-bit register, which is exactly the same size as a 32-bit integer. But not all of the floating point number is precision: some of it (8 bits, as it happens) is used to represent the exponent. So that means that a single-precision floating point number cannot represent the same amount of precision as a 32-bit integer.

Thus, when you convert a 32-bit integer to single-precision floating point, some loss of precision is to be expected. If you want to not lose precision, you should use the more common double-precision floating point format, which uses 64 bits, including 53 bits of precision.